# Is it possible to have an annulus of convergence of a power series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider a power series of the form $$1+z+z^2+z^3+\ldots$$ which converges in the complex plane for $|z|<1$ i.e. it converges inside a circle centered at $z=0$ and of radius $1$. I used the simple ratio test to find this.

Are there examples of a complex power series that, instead of converging inside a circle, converges inside an annular region in the complex plane? If so, given the series, how does one determine the annulus of convergence? Thanks.

Comment: No, if $\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n z^n$ converges then $\sup |a_n z^n| < R$ so that $\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n (rz)^n$ converges absolutely for all $|r|< 1$.

Comment: you can anyway add two power series, one in $z$ and one in $z^{-1}$, such that the former converges in a disk, the latter in the complement of another disk, hence for suitable choices you get something converging only in an annulus

Comment: @GiulioR If you do that, the result really isn't a power series any longer (though it is a Laurent series).

Comment: @XanderHenderson My math vocab is not good. By power series, I (erroneously) meant a series containing both positive and negative powers of $z$. Sorry about that.

Comment: @GiulioR Suppose I write a sum of two power series, one is a power series of $z$ and the other is a power series of $1/z$. Let the first series converges inside a disc $D_1$ and the second series inside a disc $D_2$. Then it might be possible that for some values of $z$, the sum of the two series converges only in $D_1\cap D_2$. Is this right?

Comment: Assume that the power series $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n^+ z^n$ converges in a disk $|z|<r_+$ and  the power series $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n^{-} z^n$ converges in a disk $|z|<r_-$. Then the Laurent series $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n^{+} z^n+\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n^{-} z^{-n}$ converges only in the annulus (possibly empty) $r_-^{-1}<|z|<r_+$. You can construct explicit examples to clarify the concept.